# Water pressure regulator bad?

Tags: plumbing

I checked my water pressure. It was 100! But after I adjusted it to 60 my water pressure immediately dropped to 20 after opening cold or hot faucet! Is my water pressure regulator is going bad?

Comment: So it's 60 psi with valves closed, and 20 psi with them open? Or it was 60 psi, then you opened and closed the valves, and now it's 20 psi with the valves closed?

Comment: Is this a regulator on a city supply, or is it a pressure switch on a well system and/or pressure pump?

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard anything as strange as trying to adjust your water pressure with a tap running, this makes no sense at all.

Turn your pump off, run the water until your pressure drops to about 30 psi, then flip on the pump again and see what pressure the pump stops at. if it's below 45 psi then turn the adjusting nut clockwise until the pump restarts and wait to see what pressure it stops at. If you want 60 psi then just continue adjusting until you reach the 60 psi you're after and that's it. If it won't go up to 60 psi then it could be the regulator isn't designed to go this high and you need the proper one to get the pressure you're after.

Comment: I rather suspect there is no pump or pump switch here, it's a pressure regulator from a city water supply...

Comment: Ok then you are someplace down south of here where they do things strangely but the same procedure applies, you have all taps closed after turning off the valve from the city supply. Normally all I've ever seen in city supplied water none give you a regulator and they maintain about 65 psi. so turn off the valve drop the pressure by opening a tap for a while, close the tap and open the valve and adjust the presure as described before.

Answer (score 0):

While awaiting an answer to the question Tester101 asked in coments, how to do it and what it means when....

To adjust properly:

- unlock adjustment if there is a locknut
- open a faucet and let water run -
- adjust to desired pressure
- lock adjustment if there is a locknut.
- Close faucet, ensure that no other source is using water.

Watch the pressure gauge while no water is being used. If it rises from the set pressure, the pressure regulator is probably not working correctly. Probably, because it's possible for other factors to cause a pressure rise (lack of or failed expansion tank for a water heater, for instance.) But that's not likely if you only opened a cold water faucet while adjusting the set pressure.

Comment: If a faucet is open while you're adjusting the regulator, how will you know when you've reached the desired pressure?

Comment: @Tester101 by observing the pressure gauge. If your water pressure at the service entrance is greatly affected by having a single faucet open, you have issues with your water supply...

Comment: I've never seen, or heard of anybody adjusting the pressure with a valve open.  Typically you adjust a bit, open and close a valve, take a reading, repeat.

Comment: can you clarify how much pressure difference you can expect once you shut your water tap?